# Codeigniter Image upload ignore allowed types and file size

Tags: php, codeigniter, image-uploading

I have below code to upload user image,  my code work good but I'm getting issue while checking `allowed_types` i.e. `png|jpg` and `max_size`..
It doesn't check **allowed type** and **max size**

Code:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = 'admin/upload/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg';
$config['max_size'] = '100';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('user_image')){ 
    $data = array('msg' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $flag="1";
}else { 
    $image_path = $this->upload->data();
    $flag="2";
}
```

Output:

`$flag` always set to 2...even I uploaded file .png or .gif and same problem for `max_size`

Comment: You're loading the library twice. What happens if you remove the top line?

Comment: Have you also tried removing the "set_allowed_types()" call?

Comment: @Craig in second I have pass $config array to library....actually I want that file which user going to upload must be from allowed type..i remove set_allowed_types() but not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try increasing the max_size. Also remove the line $this->upload->set_allowed_types('*');